# Which Xcode project files can I 'exclude' from my git repo?

Tags: xcode, git

I'm working on an iOS project and am using git to do version control. I'm working on this with another developer.

Which Xcode project files should I keep in the repo and which ones can I exclude so that it doesn't affect the other developer negatively?

Here are some of the non-code files that git is telling me has been modified or added...
(BTW, these are only viewable in the OSX file manager if you "Show Package Contents" for YourProject.xcodeproj file)

**exclude ?**

- contents.xcwordspacedata (I think this is just workspace settings)
- UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate (based on the name it seems only specific to me)
- Breakpoints.xcbkptlist (...my breakpoints settings)

**INCLUDE ?**

- project.pbxproj (INCLUDE...project settings)
- *.xscheme (INCLUDE...scheme definitions)
- xschememanagement.plist (INCLUDE...scheme manager settings?)

Does this seem right?

(Just an FYI for those that want to use the exclude feature of git. Edit your .git/info/exclude file in your local repository. Put in the files or the patterns for files that you want git to ignore. For example, if you want git to ignore foo.temp, bar.temp you can put a line in the file that says *.temp)

Comment: Re your last paragraph in parantheses: It is usually more desirable to use .gitignore files placed in the appropriate directory root. A .gitignore file applies to the file system subtree of its parent directory.

Answer (score 3):

**Think this is a great place to start [Xcode .gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Xcode.gitignore)**

```
# Xcode
#
# gitignore contributors: remember to update Global/Xcode.gitignore, Objective-C.gitignore & Swift.gitignore

## Build generated
build/
DerivedData

## Various settings
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata

## Other
*.xccheckout
*.moved-aside
*.xcuserstate
```

**This one I modified [Xcode .gitignore](https://gist.github.com/kincade71/37ef5e75dd439b8f5a31) I believe it to be more comprehensive.**

```
# Xcode
#
# gitignore contributors: remember to update Global/Xcode.gitignore, Objective-C.gitignore & Swift.gitignore

## Build generated
build/
DerivedData

## Various settings
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata

## Other
*.xccheckout
*.moved-aside
*.xcuserstate
*.xcscmblueprint

## Obj-C/Swift specific
*.hmap
*.ipa

# CocoaPods
#
# We recommend against adding the Pods directory to your .gitignore. However
# you should judge for yourself, the pros and cons are mentioned at:
# http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html#should-i-check-the-    pods-directory-into-source-control
#
#Pods/

# Carthage
#
# Add this line if you want to avoid checking in source code from Carthage    dependencies.
# Carthage/Checkouts

Carthage/Build

.DS_Store
.AppleDouble
.LSOverride

 # Icon must end with two \r
Icon


# Thumbnails
._*

# Files that might appear in the root of a volume
.DocumentRevisions-V100
.fseventsd
.Spotlight-V100
.TemporaryItems
.Trashes
.VolumeIcon.icns

# Directories potentially created on remote AFP share
.AppleDB
.AppleDesktop
Network Trash Folder
Temporary Items
.apdisk
```

The above adds CocoaPods, Carthage and some others that have shown up over time.

Answer (score 3):

[This site](https://www.gitignore.io) (www.gitignore.io) lets you specify your IDE and or language and shows you a tailored .gitignore - Awesome site!

Answer (score 2):

You are definetely right about your includes, else you will be missing important information from your project file.

For the excludes, I am myself excluding breakpoints and xcuserstate, but not xcworkspacedata, as I think it does store which projects are part of a workspace.