# How do I fix a Git merge with conflicts in breakpoint's file?

Tags: git, version-control, xcode5

I have an iPad app (XCode 5, iOS 7, Git source control and Storyboards).  I have two (2) branches I'm currently working on (1.8.1 in the App Store, and 2.0.0 as the working copy).

I made a slight change to 1.8.1 for the next release and thought XCode's source control would automatically **merge** the changes into 2.0.0.  I guess I was wrong.  So I attempted to do the merge using XCode's source control, and that's where things went downhill... it went into a loop.  So, I killed XCode, and restarted it.

Now, I am attempting to do the merge using SourceTree.  It tells me I have a *merge conflict in my working copy* which is (2.0.0).  Looking at a build of 2.0.0, I see this:

```
      <BreakpointProxy
     BreakpointExtensionID = "Xcode.Breakpoint.FileBreakpoint">
     <BreakpointContent
        shouldBeEnabled = "No"
        ignoreCount = "0"
        continueAfterRunningActions = "No"
        filePath = "saori/CalendarViewController.m"
        timestampString = "404851038.443273"
<<<<<<< HEAD                              <---------------- merge conflict
        startingColumnNumber = "9223372036854775807"
        endingColumnNumber = "9223372036854775807"
        startingLineNumber = "205"
        endingLineNumber = "205"
        landmarkName = "-viewDidLoad"
=======
        startingColumnNumber = "9223372036854775807"
        endingColumnNumber = "9223372036854775807"
        startingLineNumber = "205"
        endingLineNumber = "205"
        landmarkName = "-viewDidLoad"
        landmarkType = "5">
     </BreakpointContent>
  </BreakpointProxy>
  <BreakpointProxy
     BreakpointExtensionID = "Xcode.Breakpoint.FileBreakpoint">
     <BreakpointContent
        shouldBeEnabled = "No"
        ignoreCount = "0"
        continueAfterRunningActions = "No"
        filePath = "saori/SubViewData.m"
        timestampString = "406167919.038573"
        startingColumnNumber = "9223372036854775807"
        endingColumnNumber = "9223372036854775807"
        startingLineNumber = "221"
        endingLineNumber = "221"
        landmarkName = "-drawRect:"
>>>>>>> 1.8.1
        landmarkType = "5">
     </BreakpointContent>
  </BreakpointProxy>
  <BreakpointProxy
     BreakpointExtensionID = "Xcode.Breakpoint.FileBreakpoint">
     <BreakpointContent
        shouldBeEnabled = "Yes"
        ignoreCount = "0"
        continueAfterRunningActions = "No"
<<<<<<< HEAD                                    <------- merge conflict
        filePath = "saori/SubViewData.m"
        timestampString = "406167919.038573"
        startingColumnNumber = "9223372036854775807"
        endingColumnNumber = "9223372036854775807"
        startingLineNumber = "221"
        endingLineNumber = "221"
        landmarkName = "-drawRect:"
=======
```

**UPDATE**  When I do a git status, I get the following:

```
# On branch 2.0.0
# You have unmerged paths.
#   (fix conflicts and run "git commit")   
# 
# Changes to be committed:
#
#   new file:   Resized Images/MainStoryboard.strings
#   modified:   saori/AppDelegate.h
#   modified:   saori/AppDelegate.m
#
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
#
#   both modified:      SalonBook.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/rolfmarsh.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
#   both modified:      SalonBook.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/rolfmarsh.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   Crashlytics.framework/Versions/Current
#   SalonBook.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/rolfmarsh.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist.BACKUP.5744.xcbkptlist
#   SalonBook.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/rolfmarsh.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist.BASE.5744.xcbkptlist
#   SalonBook.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/rolfmarsh.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist.LOCAL.5744.xcbkptlist
#   SalonBook.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/rolfmarsh.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist.REMOTE.5744.xcbkptlist
```

My question is: how do I fix this so I can do the merge?

Comment: To get the name of a file while in a merge conflict state, run `git status`.

Comment: @RyPeck  I did the git status and posted the results in the original question.   Can I just delete the breakpoints files?

Comment: That's a question for someone who understands xcode. Not me!

Comment: Looks to me like local editor settings that shouldn't be in git at all.

Comment: Frank Osterfield: please change your comment to an answer so I can reward points and close this question.  Thanks...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `.gitignore` to exclude breakpoints data from your project (see [Which Xcode project files can I 'exclude' from my git repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8628530/2314737)).

You will then need to clear all files that are included in `.gitignore` from the git index (cache) using `git rm -r --cached`

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m 'Removed all files that are in the .gitignore'
git push
```

Comment: sure, but this is not answering the question. i would expect how to clean pushed ignore files and how to clean git cached, etc.

Answer (score 1):

to fix this:(mac)

1. add gitignore file:

   - open the folder of your project from the terminal and press $ touch .gitignore
   - then press the command: $ vi .gitignore
   - press on the letter: i
   - add in each row the ignore text for example:
     PushFor.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/
     tapaway.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/dang.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
     tapaway.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/dang.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/
     tapaway.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/
     Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/
   - press on the escape button on your keyboard
   - press $ :x (to save it)
   - to check everything is ok on your terminal: $ cat .gitignore
2. now press the command: $ git st and see that you still have untracked files despite you just put them on gitignore, so that means you push it already to git so to fix it:
   -git --cashed (and copy the files here ) for example:
   git rm --cached Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/dang.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/xcschememanagement.plist

now commit and push!